# File sharing not working in android version 6.0 and below

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android

I am using intent filter to share the mobi files to other apps. It is working fine in android version 7.0. but it is not working lower versions. Below is my code. How can we resolve this issue?

```
Context context = MainActivity.Active.BaseContext;
           Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
           sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
           sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "");
           sendIntent.SetType("application/mobi");
           sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filepath));
                     if(sendIntent.ResolveActivity(context.PackageManager) != null)
           {
               context.StartActivity(sendIntent);
           }
```